# How online database that expose data via rest api manage their security?

Tags: database, security, rest

How do online db provider like

mongolab.com,meteor.com, which exposes their api via rest

manage security of their and user's data ?

I can view the source and easily know all the data and api key.

Comment: Most APIs of this nature require authentication. Please provide more details of how you would attack this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enforce authorization you must have an intermediary between your client and your database.  This intermediary could be written in Python/Java or another server-side language.  This code is responsible for authenticating a client and then authorizing operations on your database.

MongoDB has its own [authentication and user management system](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) and in some cases this can be used instead of an intermediary.  However, this system is very simplistic,  and usually lacks the basic functionally needed by a public API.